# iPhone:Video recording based on timer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have implemented the code to do video recording feature. It works fine on 3GS device. I want to restrict the video recording based on some timer setting. Lets say, i want to allow user to do video recording only upto 20 seconds or 35 seconds like that. How can i do that? Can i show the timer kind of control on top of media player while recording the video?

Please suggest me.

Here is my code for video recording:

```
    UIImagePickerController *pickerController = 
                       [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
    pickerController.delegate = self;
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    pickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
    pickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)kUTTypeMovie];
    [self presentModalViewController:pickerController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I saw a parameter "videoMaximumDuration" in "UIImagePickerController Class Reference". I think, i can use this for video recording to restrict the time. For ex: "pickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 15; Please advise.

Comment: have you tried, thats the best way to find out.

Comment: I'll be getting the physical 3GS device after 2 days only, so am unable to test video recording right now. Could someone help me my code and test it today if possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`videoMaximumDuration` expects an `NSTimeInterval`, which is a tpyedef for a float value. So you should pass it a float value. Try it like this:

```
UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerController.delegate = self;
pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
pickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
pickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]; // kUTTypeMovie is actually an NSString.
pickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 30.0f; // limits video length to 30 seconds.
[self presentModalViewController:pickerController animated:YES];
[pickerController release];
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIImagePickerController` class has property `videoMaximumDuration` which works for `NSTimeInterval`.

By default it's value is set for **10 minutes** but you can change it's **float value** according to your need.

So if you make object of `UIImagePickerController` class named `videoPickerController` then you can set timer for capturing video like-

```
videoPickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 25.0f;
```